# Does gsutil validate within cloud transfers?

Tags: validation, google-cloud-storage, checksum, gsutil

I will be transferring batches of valuable objects from regional to coldline Google Cloud Storage (GCS) and my client wants a guarantee that the files will not be corrupted in the process. Do objects moved within GCS, using `gsutil mv`, undergo any checksum validation?

Checking the documentation for gsutil cp (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp) I see that checksum validation is performed on all uploads and downloads, but it is unclear to me whether validation is performed on within-cloud transfers.

My intuition is that since checksum metadata is already stored as object metadata, there should be built-in validation, but I would like to get confirmation.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, objects copied in the cloud undergo checksum validation.